# Convert DDMMYYYY to YYYYMMDD date format in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a date in table as `"26052016"` in format `DDMMYYYY` 
I want to convert this date to `"YYYYMMDD"` format.

Any idea
I have tried this method

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),[doc-date],112) FROM C034_PDK_ParallelBillingSourceExtract
```

But this is gives me the same date as a result.

Please help me

Comment: What is the column name for the date column ?

Comment: The column name is "doc-date"

Comment: I'd really suggest you to update your table and have a proper data type to store your date values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find this way, i don't know if any other way exist or not..

```
declare @date nvarchar(max)='01052016'

select convert(varchar(8),cast(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@date,3,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,1,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,5,4)) as date),112)as [YYYYMMDD]
```

Clear Code:

```
declare @date nvarchar(max)='01052016'
declare @date1 date
set @date1 =cast(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@date,3,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,1,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,5,4)) as date)

select convert(varchar(8),@date1,112)as [YYYYMMDD]
```

If you are using `Sql version< 2012` then you need to skip `CONCAT` and use `+` for string concatination.

Answer (score 1):

There are differet ways to do it.

The best way is to use `substring` method as you know the character positions are going to remain same.

**For Example**

Suppose your date is - `31122015`

Pick the portions of date using `substring` method and concatenate them

```
select  SUBSTRING('31122015',5,4) + SUBSTRING('31122015',3,2) + SUBSTRING('31122015',1,2)
```

The result would be - `20153112`

Comment: This will result in `YYYYDDMM`, while the OP is asking for `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: My mistake bro, thanks for pointing it out.
For the desired results just interchange the position of 2nd and 3rd substing method. So the correct query should be -

select  SUBSTRING([doc-date],5,4) +  SUBSTRING([doc-date],3,2) + SUBSTRING([doc-date],1,2)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), doc-date, 112) AS [YYYYMMDD] from
 C034_PDK_ParallelBillingSourceExtract
```

Check ... this should work correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), '26052016', 112) AS [YYYYMMDD] from
 C034_PDK_ParallelBillingSourceExtract
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT substring([doc-date], 5, 4) + substring([doc-date], 3, 2) + substring([doc-date], 1, 2) AS [YYYYMMDD]
FROM C034_PDK_ParallelBillingSourceExtract
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2016 we have a couple of handy tools for this:

Use DATEFROMPARTS and SUBSTRING to convert odd date formats from any arrangement within a Varchar to an actual date:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING('31122015',5,4), SUBSTRING('31122015',3,2), SUBSTRING('31122015',1,2))
```

Use FORMAT to Convert an actual date to YYYYMMDD:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MyDate, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

watch out for the yyyyMMdd, that's the only part of MS SQL that **is** case-sensitive. Lower case mm is "minutes" and upper case MM is "Month", upper case YYYY or DD is nothing, and will just add letters to your output!