# convert date in string format to date datatype sql

Tags: sql, string, date, ssis

I have values in a column named Date as a nvarachar data type in the form of mmddyy and want to convert the values to a date datatype in the form of yyyy-mm-dd, what sql colde can I use to convert the value.

example
02121955 -> 1955-02-12

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(right(str, 4), left(str, 2), substring(str, 3, 2))
```

Or reconstruct it as yyyymmdd format and just convert:

```
select convert(date, left(right(str, 4) + str, 8))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2a03bf3b0bd5e964bdca051df5967db) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar Question to yours that has been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39139155/14940878

Here is the Code changed for your requests:

`declare @date varchar(max)='02121955'`

`select convert(varchar(8),cast(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@date,5,4),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,1,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,3,2)) as date),112)as [YYYYMMDD]`

You need to take each field and concat it into one and then convert it to datetime.

`SUBSTRING(@date,5,4) - Takes the last four characters.`

`SUBSTRING(@date,1,2) - Takes the first two.`

`SUBSTRING(@date,3,2) - Takes the two in the middle.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's SQL Server, I think you just need

```
select cast(format(02121955,'##-##-####') as date)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=be0147c0815f4efc704e79063a91993d)